# Reverse the order of pairs

Tags: racket, reverse

I am trying to write a function in Racket that will reverse the order of pairs.  For example, given the list '(1 2) the function should produce '(2 1).  Here is my code so far:

```
(define (reverse aList)
    (cons (second aList)
        (first aList))
```

This is not producing the correct answer, however.  When I test with **'(a b)** it returns **'(b . a)** instead of **'(b a).**  How do I get rid of the **period** between the b and a?

Answer (score 2):

You should have:

```
(define (reverse-pair lst)
  (cons (second lst) (cons (first lst) empty)))
```

As stated in Racket's [docs](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Pairs__Lists__and_Racket_Syntax.html):

> The cons function actually accepts any two values, not just a list for the second argument. When the second argument is not empty and not itself produced by cons, the result prints in a special way. The two values joined with cons are printed between parentheses, but with a dot (i.e., a period surrounded by whitespace) in between.

So,

```
> (cons 1 2)
'(1 . 2)
> (cons 1 (cons 2 empty))     ; equivalent to (list 1 2)
'(1 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much Alexander!!